Material on object not visualizing in Cycles/Evee, except workbench
I have downloaded this Car blend file from the Internet a long time ago, and chose to use it today.

It's completely dark in cycles (even with lights)
It's completely dark in evee as well
Its yellow/materialized in Workbench
The main material color from external folder seems to be blue.
And the nodes are all in red.




I can't work with a black/dark mesh. How do I fix the problem.
Blend File: https://workupload.com/file/r2BeaZKpYgF

hello please share your file

@moonboots I had tried to. The file size is 46.8mb, and Blend.Exchange says I can't upload a file size more than 30mb.

use another platform like workupload, or only share a piece of the object

@moonboots I've included the Blend file via workupload link.

It looks like the material was made with node groups but they are not working anymore, their color is red and if you press Tab they are empty, they may have been created with an old version of Blender?

It looks like the material was made with node groups but they are not working anymore, their color is red and if you press Tab they are empty, they may have been created with an old version of Blender, maybe the old Blender render engine?
